# Questions about ruby directory install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm installing ruby on my system and I'm getting an error `You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory`.

As far as I understand, there is a local version of ruby that the system uses already on my machine. How can I ensure that I'm not trying to write to that directory as opposed to the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Just install Ruby as a sudo(maybe root).

But Im strongly recommend to use RVM(Ruby Version Manager). 
It's deadly simple install ruby over system ruby.

cheers, humbroll.